# Python: two layer of Dictionary

Tags: python

everyone, I have a question about python dict, currently, I want to store some value with 2 layers (parent), something like below

this is the original

```
David= {'Date of birth': '12111922','Age': 7, 'Height ': '1.7m'}
```

but I want to add one more layer(parent on top) :

```
Character = {David {'Date of birth': '12111922','Age': 7, 'Height ': '1.7m'}}
```

Comment: your desired output is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: I'm confused, you literally wrote the code, minus a `:`, `Character = {'David' :{'Date of birth': '12111922','Age': 7, 'Height ': '1.7m'}}`

Comment: @eagle you are right! I'ms so silly~~~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @eagle said in the comment, the short version is

```
Character = {
    'David' : {
        'Date of birth': '12111922',
        'Age': 7,
        'Height' : '1.7m'
     }
}
```

Or you could do it step by step if it is clearer to you:

```
David = {}
David['Date of birth'] = '12111922'
David['Age'] = 7
David['Height'] = '1.7m'

Character = {}
Character['David'] = David
```